# Storing NSManagedObject in a dictionary (NSDictionary)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, nsdictionary, nsmanagedobject

I have a custom class, which is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`. I would like to store it in a dictionary, but when trying to do so I receive a `Property list invalid for format: 200` error.

Here is how I try to create the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: voiceMemo forKey:@"voiceMemo"];
```

Same result when trying

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: (NSData *) voiceMemo forKey:@"voiceMemo"];
```

It works, however, when trying to save the individual attributes separately:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: voiceMemo.attribute forKey:@"attribute"];
```

`NSDictionary` should be able to store data objects, so I'm guessing, the real question is how to cast an `NSManagedObject` object to `NSData`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Are you sure the error happens when you create the dictionary like it is implied by the code you have posted?

`Property list invalid for format: 200` sounds like you try to write your `NSManagedObject` to the file system. Which won't work, because `NSManagedObjects` don't confirm to `NSCoding`.

You could save the attributes of the NSManagedObject in a NSDictionary, and save this dictionary to a file..

```
NSArray *keys = [[[myObject entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
NSDictionary *dict = [myObject dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
```

and when you want to restore it you set the values of your managedObject like this:

```
[myObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
```

Comment: You are right, the error occurs at the next line, when I am attempting to write the data (in this case in a UILocalNotification's userData). As I wrote in the question, saving the attributes separately does work, so this solves the problem. I just thought (or hoped) that there was a way to get around this. Thank you!

Comment: I searched Google for get array of keys, NSArray *keys = [[[myObject entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
 is best than other answers thank you!

Comment: @Matthias how should i get the relationship objects in same dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

In my app I'm also storing MO's in a dictionary (but no hold on, I'm storing in an array) but without any cast. please try if this happens for an array too.

And you can try to create the dictionary first and after that assign objects.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dic setValue:managedObject forKey:@"thisOne"];
```

Answer (score 0):

A swift version in case anyone needs it

```
import CoreData 
extension NSManagedObject {
    func toDict() -> [String:Any] {
        let keys = Array(entity.attributesByName.keys)
        return dictionaryWithValues(forKeys:keys)
    }
}
```